# Removing the default tabbar color iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

i want to place the background image to default tabbar here i added the code for background tabbar background image  but it appears both my background image and also default tabbar also please suggest for removing the default tabbar black color image .Plz refer the below image for better understanding

Thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code:

```
// this will generate a gray tab bar
tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false;
// this will give selected icons and text your apps tint color
tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];  // appTintColor is a UIColor *
```